# Hadoop 2.2.0 Streaming Memory Limitation

Tags: bash, memory, hadoop, hadoop-streaming, hadoop-yarn

We have a very frustrating hadoop streaming memory problem, our setup:

- hadoop 2.2.0 (yarn)
- our compute nodes have about **7 GB of RAM**
- hadoop streaming starts a bash script wich uses about **4 GB of RAM**
- therefore it is only possible to start one and only **one task per node**

out of the box each hadoop instance starts about 7 hadoop containers with default hadoop settings. each hadoop task forks a bash script that need about 4 GB of RAM, the first fork works, all following fail because **they run out of memory**. so what we are looking for is to **limit** the number of containers **to only one**. so what we found on the internet:

- `yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb` and `mapreduce.map.memory.mb` is set to values such that there is at most one container. this means, `mapreduce.map.memory.mb` must be  **more than half** of the maximum memory (otherwise there will be multiple containers).

done right, this gives us one container per node. but it produces a new problem: since our java process is now using at least half of the max memory, our child (bash) process we fork will **inherit the parent memory footprint** and since the memory used by our parent was more than half of total memory, **we run out of memory again**. if we lower the map memory, hadoop will allocate 2 containers per node, which will run out of memory too.

we would be very happy for any help offered! Thanks!

edit: since this problem is a blocker in our project we are evaluating adapting the source code to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the solution is to set the initial memory footprint of hadoop children via:

```
<property>
  <name>mapreduce.map.child.java.opts</name>
  <value>-Xmx512</value>
</property>
```

and we also set following parameters to the same value, just to be sure (they set heap sizes of child processes):

```
yarn.app.mapreduce.am.command-opts
```

which sets the MR App Master processes heap size.

the number of hadoop containers can be set via the pattern described above. important to note: there must be at least the amount of `mapreduce.map.child.java.opts` free to be able to spawn child processes. we used:

```
mapreduce.map.memory.mb = yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb - mapreduce.map.child.java.opts
```

everything works smoothly now. hope this may help someone in the future!